# How to identify C++ file linkage in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I'm going through an old C++ solution in Visual Studio, and referencing certain sections for a new project. One file has this declaration:

```
vector <cDevice*> localdevices;
```

Visual Studio happily shows me where the "vector" type is defined, but I want to know exactly *how* the solution references that file. According to the "Find in Files" tool, there is no other use of the text "vector" in the solution, and the file isn't among the "Additional includes" either. How does the project "know" what a vector is?

Edit: The project does not build, and I don't feel like fixing that, since I'm ultimately trying to rewrite the code anyway.

Comment: The code probably includes some standard header that in turn happens to `#include <vector>`

Comment: Is "<vector>" not included somewhere? If not then does the code actually build? It may just be an intellisense error.

Comment: Use Project + Properties, C/C++, Advanced, "Show Includes" = Yes.  You'll see how headers got included in the Output window.

Comment: Intellisense knows about the standard library whether the solution references it or not